# Using JSON for Modern c++ and Gradle Android Studio

Tags: android, c++, json, stl

I am trying to use https://github.com/nlohmann/json in my Android app with C++. The issue is that when I go to build I get the error "no member named 'to_string' in namespace 'std'". I have followed the instructions on the Github for Android, except I have used Gradle to specify the `stl` and flags:

```
ndk {
    stl "c++_static"
}

externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        cppFlags "-fexceptions -frtti -std=c++11"
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to make this library work on Android and use Gradle to set the `stl` properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I needed this instead (I have not looked into why though because the docs say what I posted should work):

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        cppFlags "-fexceptions -frtti -std=c++11"
        arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"
    }
}
```